# .NET strange behaviour with datetimes and UTC to local time conversion

Tags: vb.net, datetime, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I'm modifying and old app and I found a big bug. I'm in Spain and this app is reading some files here which contain a date in a UTC string format, and is needed to be converted.

The string value is already converted to local time with `CDate` due to the format:
`"yyyy-MM-yyTHH:mmZ"`

But the code here converts again the date to a local value with `.ToLocalTime`, presumably making the time change again to a incorrect value.

The strange fact occurs now, where the var is taking the correct value, but the code is not returning that. In the "Inspection" secion in the Visual Studio you can see that the result should be 0, not 22 (hour 0 of next day).

[image: Visual Studio error]

What is happening here?

**EDIT:**

The app is reading a XML file, and in this point is reading this:

```
<IntervaloTiempo v="2013-10-26T19:33Z/2013-10-26T22:00Z"/>
```

The code is the one shown in the screenshot:

```
Valor = Split(.Value, "/")

dtUTC = CDate(Valor(0)) 
iHoraIn = Hour(dtUTC.ToLocalTime().AddHours(1))
```

I corrected the code with this, and the app is working the same way:

```
iHoraIn = dtUTC.AddHours(1).Hour
```

**EDIT2:**

Since it looks that my post is difficult to understand as seen in comments, I'll try clarify on some things.

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 with .NET Framework 2.0.

The value in `dtUTC` is converted to local time and its value, as you can see in the screenshot, is `21:33`, which should return `22` with `AddHour(1).Hour`.

When using `dtUTC.ToLocalTime()` its hour should be converted to `23:33` value, which should return `0` with `AddHour(1).Hour`.

As you can see in the "Inspection" window, that is the behaviour. The problem is, the final value of the var `iHoraIn` is `22`, which is correct, but the code is not.

Actually, changing the code to just deleting the `ToLocalTime()` part makes the final value the same.

**Can someone explain why and how this is happening? Is this a bug?**

Comment: would be nice to also add code instead to have us to come up with it. btw screenshot is nice.

Comment: This is a @jon-skeet question, since hes a DateTime expert!

Comment: The reason for 22 is clear from your results (as explained in the answers): 9:33 (21:33) +1 = 22. In any case, you shouldn't be relying on CDate, but on other approaches (ideally a newer .NET one) accounting for the exact date format (via CultureInfo or, in this case, the target string format).

Comment: I have read your comment below. What you mean with differences in execution/compiler? I am executing your code (am in Spain) and I get the expected result everywhere, that is, 22 hours.

Comment: @varocarbas Maybe I didn't explained properly. `Cdate` already converts string date to local time, and as you can see in "Inspection" window, the code returns 0. But the var is taking value 22. And this app is not mine, I'm just amazed of this trange behaviour

Comment: @SysDragon, which version of visual studio and .net?

Comment: This was a general suggestion, not just in this case (that is: better make sure that the date format is accounted for properly instead of trusting blindly on CDate to recognise it). As explained above, I am executing your code and I get always 22 hours; perhaps you should confirm that everything is OK in your test or post the exact conditions (iHoraIn = dtUTC.AddHours(1).Hour should delivers 22 in VS 2010, Spain)

Comment: @Fredou Is Visual Studio 2005 and framework 2.0

Comment: There you have your problem!!! You have to mention this kind of issues!!! Up to VS 2008 is acceptable, older than that is old enough to, at least, mention it in the title/tag.

Comment: I just tried this under visual studio 2012 but using .net 2.0, i do not have this issue. this might be a visual studio 2005 issue. sadly i don't have it.

Comment: in any case, for "best practice" or "better use", try to use .net call, ex; datetime.parse(), instead of the old vb6 syntax; cdate(). this will not solve your issue. i just wish microsoft would put obsolete attribute on these...

Comment: @varocarbas sorry, I've made another edit to clarify things

Comment: @Fredou I always use another methods, this code was like that.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough either: the problem is VS 2005; it is too old (until 2008, VS should show an equivalent behaviour; and thus not being influential for any problem). I have run your conditions on a computer located in Spain (with Spain-location settings in Windows), with .NET 2.0 in VS 2010 and 2008 and I am not able to replicate your problem. So, my conclusion is: the problem is VS 2005, better don't use it (you shouldn't be using a so old IDE anyway).

Comment: @varocarbas I can't decide which program or framework to use T_T Believe me... I'm the first one that wants to get upgraded.

Comment: Kind of funny reading this after having written a short while ago something on these lines (let's call it "Spanish peculiarities" :)). I am afraid that you cannot find a solution for this; other than trying a different thing: in .NET, there are usually more than one way to accomplish the same thing (as said, CDate is not even the most recommendable approach); do some tests by using different approaches delivering the same result, but avoiding this problem. I am afraid that this is something you have to do by your own (or add "VS 2005" in title/tag and wait for someone having it installed).

Comment: @varocarbas No, I already solve the "problem". The app is working now with the code improved. I'm just wondering how this behaviour could be possible and I was expecting someone to explain me why

Comment: I updated the tag for .net 2.0 and vs2005

Comment: @SysDragon, can you provide you solution in a answer form and accept your own answer?

Comment: @Fredou I think you guys are not understanding the question... I still don't know why this is happening, and that is the question. The app was not even failing... My upgrade of that code it's not relevant in the thing that I question here.

Comment: I told you already what is the problem: you shouldn't be using a so old IDE (and your employer shouldn't make you work under these conditions). The only solution is locating the problem and avoiding it. If you have located the problem and found a way to avoid it; please describe it in detail (this is what Fredou requested from you): your conditions, what didn't work and what made it work (= the workaround you used to avoid the problem). Future readers might find it helpful.

Comment: @varocarbas You are not understanding what I mean. I understand that the problem could be the IDE. There is no sense in adding my final code. If you request that, you are not understanding the question.

Comment: I do understand the question (= "how can I avoid this to happen under my exact conditions in VS 2005"); but you are not understanding neither the solution I proposed (= "it is most likely a VS 2005 bug which cannot be fixed; the most logical solution is avoiding this situation or, ideally, not using VS 2005 at all") nor the request we made (= "you have spotted a bug in VS 2005 which some other person might also find; please, provide the code you used to avoid this problem. This might be helpful for future readers, as far as this is the practical solution here: avoiding it").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DateTime.Kind**

In Version 2.0 of the .Net framework, Microsoft introduced the [DateTime.Kind property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The different kinds are as follows:

```
Local
Unspecified
Utc
```

Every `Date` (the underlying CLR type is `DateTime`) object has the `Kind` property, which specifies what kind of date that object is. That is, it specifies whether the date value is local, UTC, or unknown.

If a `Date` object has `Kind = Local`, then no conversion is performed when the `ToLocalTime` function is called. From the [DateTime.ToLocalTime method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), emphasis is mine:

```
Kind        Results (of ToLocalTime)
----------- -----------------------------------------
Utc         This instance of DateTime is converted to local time.
Local       No conversion is performed.
Unspecified This instance of DateTime is assumed to be a UTC time,
            and the conversion is performed as if Kind were UTC.
```

**How does this apply to your situation?**

When you use `CDate`, the resulting `Kind` is `Local`. This means that when you call `ToLocal` on it, no conversion takes place:

```
Dim valor = "2013-10-26T19:33Z"
Dim dtUTC = CDate(valor)
' dtUTC.Kind is Local
' The following does not do any conversion
Dim dtLocal = dtUTC.ToLocal()
```

**A more complete example**

This example shows what happens when you use `CDate`, and what happens when the `Kind` is explicitly set. The first two code blocks are equivalent - `CDate` creates a `Local` date. The third block shows what happens when you specify a UTC date.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim valor = "2013-10-26T19:33Z"

    Dim dtUTC = CDate(valor)
    Dim dtLocal = dtUTC.ToLocalTime()
    Dim iHoraIn = Hour(dtLocal.AddHours(1))
    Dim kind = dtUTC.Kind
    printDate(dtUTC, dtLocal, iHoraIn, kind)

    Dim dtUTC2 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dtUTC, DateTimeKind.Local)
    Dim dtLocal2 = dtUTC2.ToLocalTime()
    Dim iHoraIn2 = Hour(dtLocal2.AddHours(1))
    Dim kind2 = dtUTC2.Kind
    printDate(dtUTC2, dtLocal2, iHoraIn2, kind2)

    Dim dtUTC3 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dtUTC, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    Dim dtLocal3 = dtUTC3.ToLocalTime()
    Dim iHoraIn3 = Hour(dtLocal3.AddHours(1))
    Dim kind3 = dtUTC3.Kind
    printDate(dtUTC3, dtLocal3, iHoraIn3, kind3)
End Sub

Sub printDate(ByVal dtUtc, ByVal dtLocal, ByVal hora, ByVal utcKind)
    System.Console.WriteLine("UTC: {0}, UTC KIND: {1}, LOCAL: {2}, HORA: {3}", dtUtc, utcKind, dtLocal, hora)
End Sub
```

The above produces this output:

```
UTC: 2013-10-26 09:33:00 PM, UTC KIND: Local, LOCAL: 2013-10-26 09:33:00 PM, HORA: 22
UTC: 2013-10-26 09:33:00 PM, UTC KIND: Local, LOCAL: 2013-10-26 09:33:00 PM, HORA: 22
UTC: 2013-10-26 09:33:00 PM, UTC KIND: Utc, LOCAL: 2013-10-26 11:33:00 PM, HORA: 0
```

So what you are seeing is not a bug - it is expected behavior. You are trying to convert what you think is a UTC Date; however in reality it is really a local date.

I believe what you are expecting to see is what happens in the third code block above. It creates a UTC date and converts it to local time.

Comment: That is just what I wanted to know. I knew there was an explanation. Very nice answer, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

what happen here is

```
Sub Main()
    Dim valor = "2013-10-26T19:33Z" 

    'this convert to local time
    Dim dtUTC = CDate(valor) 

    'this add one hour to local time in 24 hour format
    'equal to dtUTC.AddHours(1).Hour 
    Dim iHoraIn = dtUTC.ToLocalTime.AddHours(1).Hour 
End Sub
```

`2013-10-26T19:33Z` is `2013-10-26 15:33` in my time zone, `dtUTC` show this time

i'm adding 1 hour to it so `iHoraIn` is now 16

---

in your screenshot, the watch show `dtUTC` as `9:33 PM` which is `21` hour

you add 1 hour which now is `22` hour

is this what you expect?

Comment: The correct result is `22`, but the code is returning different values in the execution and in the compiler

Comment: @SysDragon, in the watch where you see 0, do you have a little icon "refresh" in the far right of the 0? click on it